# Registering server events with flask SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm getting started with flask and SocketIO using https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO.

I want to post a string to the flask server and then via SocketIO, emit this to the client webpage.

Normally my posting code would look like:

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():
    token = request.form['token']
```

As far as I understand, something like the following is needed to emit data from the server to client page:

```
@socketio.on('event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=False)
```

It's not clear to me how to tie the 2 functions together so that on a post the value of token would be emitted to the client.

The closest I can find in the docs is:

```
Receiving Messages¶
When using SocketIO messages are received by both parties as events. On the client side Javascript callbacks are used. With Flask-SocketIO the server needs to register handlers for these events, similarly to how routes are handled by view functions.
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right with your assumptions. First, [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the data to Flask:

```
.ajax({
    url: "{{ url_for('index') }}",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        token: "value"
    }
});
```

Your [view](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py) would look like

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():
    token = request.form['token']
    test_message(dict(data=token))
    return '1'
```

And your [JavaScript](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/templates/index.html) would look something like

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
});
socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
    // do something with msg.data
});
```

Comment: The error I had was when I removed the line @socketio.on('event', namespace='/test') from @socketio.on('event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message): after that it started working. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Sorry I meant 'the error was fixed' not 'the error I had'