# Displaying client side values with socketIO

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I'm getting started with flask and SocketIO using https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO.

[image]

I want to post a string to the flask server and then via SocketIO, emit this to the client webpage.

I am using postman to post the token value. Please see screenshot.

My flask server looks like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

#turn the flask app into a socketio app
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    #only by sending this page first will the client be connected to the socketio instance
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/ul')
def ul_connect():

    # print('here is ul '+ul)
    print('Client connected')

@app.route('/posting',methods=['POST'])
def posting():
        token = request.form['token']
        test_message(dict(data=token))
        return '1'

@socketio.on('posting', namespace='/ul')
def test_message(message):
    socketio.emit('response', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=False)


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/ul')
def ul_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__
```

My client webpage contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//connect to the socket server.
var namespace = 'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/ul';
var socket = io.connect(namespace);
console.log('namespace ',namespace)


//var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
});
socket.on('response', function(msg) {
    // do something with msg.data
    console.log('response', msg.data)
});
```

When I post the token I see nothing in my console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your example, you are mixing Flask/HTTP and Socket.IO data in an invalid way.

Your first problem is to identify the user that sent the POST request, so that you can locate his/her Socket.IO connection. This is easier said than done, there is no connection between HTTP requests and a Socket.IO connection, so you'll have to add some sort of authentication on both sides, or if you prefer something simpler, just record the user's `REMOTE_ADDR` (which is not always reliable).

So first step is to keep track of users that are connected over Socket.IO (I'll use the remote address for simplicity):

```
socketio_clients = {}

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/ul')
def ul_connect():
    socketio_clients[request.remote_addr] = request.namespace
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/ul')
def ul_disconnect():
    del socketio_clients[request.remote_addr]
    print('Client disconnected')
```

Now on your `POST` request you can find the user and emit a message:

```
@app.route('/posting',methods=['POST'])
def posting():
    token = request.form['token']
    client_namespace = socketio_clients.get(request.remote_addr)
    if client_namespace:
        client_namespace.emit('response', {'data': token}))
        return '1'
    abort(400)  # client does not have a socket connection active
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this Miguel, I was following up my last post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141887/registering-server-events-with-flask-socketio, and the answer given by Celeo

Comment: I fixed my problem by removing  @socketio.on('posting', namerspace='ul'  from in front of  @socketio.on('posting', namespace='/ul')
 def test_message(message):

Comment: I think you are answering a more complicated problem, but I'll keep it in mind for when I become more advanced with socketIO. Best Regards.

Comment: Well, I think you are still not doing it right. The `socketio.emit()` call in your `test_message` function is going to broadcast the message to all connected users, that function does not know the user. Connect from multiple clients to check that you get the behavior that you expect.

Comment: Understood, at this point I was just trying to get any kind of connection at all, and was having trouble with that. Now that I have some basic working code, I can layer on more complexity. Thanks again.